# XML Serializer C# Namespaces Duplicate Issue

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am using XmlSerializer in C# to generate an XML document based on a model.  I need to generate the following XML root that contains a duplicate namespace using separate prefixes. Below is what the output should look like…

```
<ClinicalDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA_SDTC.xsd"
 xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"
 xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3"
 xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">
```

However, when I Serialize this, the default entry is removed (which contains the duplicate namespace) and the root is prefixed.

```
<cda:ClinicalDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cda="urn:hl7-org:v3">
```

Here is my XmlSerializer code...

```
var writer = new XmlSerializer(clinicalDocument.GetType(),"urn:hl7-org:v3");

            var myNamespace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

            myNamespace.Add("sdtc", "urn:hl7-org:sdtc");
            myNamespace.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            myNamespace.Add("cda", "urn:hl7-org:v3");


            using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(CCDUncOutputPath))
            {
                writer.Serialize(file, clinicalDocument, myNamespace);
                file.Close();
            };

            writer = null; 

            GC.Collect();
```

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Main question is what for you need namespace duplicates? It look's like something wrong in other place. And what for `file.Close()` invocation if you are using `using` statement? I'm scare to ask what `GC.Collect()` for.

Comment: Also namespace duplicate prefix is useless if on other side are correct xml analizer, because all elements are in same namespace.